# Long lived HttpClient created by HttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, object-lifetime, httpclientfactory

I've read that `HttpMessageHandlers` are recycled every 2 minutes, but I'm not sure if a new one is assigned to an existing `HttpClient`?

I've tested it out by using `SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));` and even after 2 minutes with countless requests, the httpClient is continuing to work, which is a good sign?

Does that mean that I have no cause for concern with DNS changes/socket exhaustion?

Inside **ConfigureServices** method:

```
var myOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions>>();
HttpClient httpClient = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient();
MyStaticObject.Configure(myOptions, httpClient);
```

**EDIT:** Added some sample code.

Comment: Where are you instantiating your HttpClient? If you are using HttpClientFactory it will handle the lifetime for you. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

Comment: @TylerHundley in ConfigureServices, I'm creating a default HttpClient (not typed, not named, just by directly using `HttpClientFactory.CreateClient` method without any additional parameters.

Comment: @TylerHundley the instance I create there, I pass to a static field, which will continue to live throughout the rest of the application's lifetime. Is that okay? As far as I understood from you, the `HttpMessageHandlers` are indeed recycled every 2 minutes, with new ones, avoiding the previous issues found in singleton `HttpClients`?

Comment: Where are you using `HttpClientFactory.CreateClient`? Are you using dependency injection? Can you add some sample code of where you are declaring/using your client?

Comment: @TylerHundley done! Thank you for trying to help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to look at here, with the first being does `MyStaticObject` actually need to be static? If it does, I would recommend instead registering it as a Singleton so that you can still leverage dependency injection. Once you have done that, you can register `IHttpClientFactory` and use it from your code. Your `ConfigureServices` method may end up looking something like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //The base extension method registers IHttpClientFactory
  services.AddHttpClient();
  services.AddSingleton<IMySingletonObject, MySingletonObject>();
}
```

Then in your consuming class, `MySingletonObject` in this case, you would configure it as such

```
public class MySingletonObject
{
  private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

  public MySingletonObject(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
  {
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
  }

  public async Task SomeMethodThatUsesTheClient()
  {
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    //use the client
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that `IHttpClientFactory` handles the lifetime and pool concerns for us. Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#consumption-patterns):

> Manages the pooling and lifetime of underlying HttpClientMessageHandler instances. Automatic management avoids common DNS (Domain Name System) problems that occur when manually managing HttpClient lifetimes.

This happens when you make the `CreateClient` call, so you want to do this inside the code using the client, as opposed to on startup of your application.

As a side note, if you do not need this class to be a singleton at all, you can use the extenion `services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>()` and inject an `HttpClient` directly into the class. The DI container will handle getting a client from the factory behind the scenes for you.

Comment: I can't get into the specifics, but the static class is an attribute, and it'd be very wrong to allow dependency injection in it, when it's being used as an attribute, not a service.

Hence why I did it via the above way. If I skip all of that, and stick to my own version, will that cover all my concerns and problems with the HttpClient? I don't see why not, as you're just passing an HttpClient from DI, rather than getting it directly from the HttpClientFactory (which is documented to be a valid option)

Comment: When you pass in an HttpClient you do it to classes that are scoped, so it is passed every time. In Singleton instances you pass the entire factory, and then use CreateClient to get a client when needed. If you must stay with static, I would pass in the entire HttpClientFactory through the Configure method and use it as shown in my example above

Comment: I'm not convinced that what you're saying there is entirely correct, because it'd make no sense. Why would I need to create multiple httpClients after every request? Isn't that against what the httpClientFactory is all about? Furthermore, an alternative to HttpClientFactory, which is `SocketsHttpHandler`, would solve my problem with 2 lines of code. And I'm 100% sure that a httpClient created that way, will indeed recycle `httpMessageHandlers` as well as refreshing DNS cache. Why wouldn't that exact same thing apply to instances created by `httpClientFactory`?

Comment: My example code is taken directly from Microsoft's example of usage for `HttpClientFactory` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#basic-usage). You can see the underlying issues with `HttpClient` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#issues-with-the-original-httpclient-class-available-in-net-core). Notice you are not creating a client multiple times per request, just once when you need it. (1/2)

Comment: The  `HttpClientFactory` caches the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` which is where the issue of socket exhaustion normally comes from. (2/2)

Comment: You are showing the example usage for DI. Nowhere does it say that for singletons I should be feeding it a factory, and issuing a new httpClient per request sent. That seems like insanity.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but under the covers it seems you're also not entirely sure as to how these things operate. I've read through that whole page, which prompted me to open this question to make sure I understood it right. So far, your answers/comments are sourced by that very page, yet the specific question I'm asking is **yet to be answered**.

Comment: Even though you are creating a new `HttpClient` per request, the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` is being reused. This is the component that caused the issue with socket exhaustion. Using the same `HttpClient` instance for the lifetime of the app prevents it from respecting DNS changes afaik because even if you are using `HttpClientFactory` to create the client you are still using the same client the whole time. You may as well be newing up an `HttpClient` to use. This is why I suggested passing the factory to a singleton or static object. Objects with a lifetime get a client from factory(1/2)

Comment: every time they are newed up by DI. Singleton and static objects are not, so you are doing this yourself by calling `CreateClient` in your method. In regards to the original question, you are probably safe as far as socket exhaustion because using a single client prevents that. You most likely are not safe regarding DNS changes because using a single client doesn't respect DNS changes, that was the whole purpose of the factory to begin with. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static IServiceCollection AddApiClient(this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<RgCommunicationClientOptions> action)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<ISomeApiClient, SomeApiClient>()
            .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy())
            .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure(action);

        return services;
    }
    
    static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
    {
        return HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            //.OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
    }

 services.AddApiClient(options => options.BaseAddress = configuration.GetSection("ExternalServices:SomeApi")["Url"]);
```

> You can inject HttpClient like above in the class via dependency injection. I have used Poly extension to add RetryPolicy. Also you can set the LifetTime of the handler by using SetHaandlerLifeTime. This way you can individually configure client for each client. In the logs you can see that httpHandler expires after 4 mins for the respective call. I have used the extension method to pass the options in the method, getting values via app settings.
> Hope this helps.
> Blockquote